# Custom Sink : Multiple Backends

Tags: tap, spring-xd, sink

I have a scenario that I need to update or Insert data to multiple datastores. This is no orchetration of logic just insert/update data. But Multiple backends. Say Oracle, Mongo, DB2 etc. There are multiple ways to achieve it. We are looking at the options:

1) Use tap to update different backends on the main stream. I am concerned that this is antipattern to WireTap pattern. Please advice.

2) Cleaner approach I see is to develop a Custom Sink to update different backends using Spring Integration. Is this approach a valid/agreeable pattern?

Please provide your inputs on which is the right way to achieve this usecase.

Thanks
Karthik

Comment: Your question is too broad - There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow down the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Can I create a Custom Sink to update multiple datastores, is this a agreeable pattern in XD as it advices only one Sink?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Use tap to update different backends on the main stream. I am concerned that this is antipattern to WireTap pattern. Please advice.

Not sure I understand what you mean by anti-pattern. The way `tap` works in Spring XD is that you connect to a pub/sub on the message-bus (`topic` for kafka and `exchange` for rabbit) to receive the tapped data.

The actual wire-tap channel (SI channel created for the message output module) would still have a `single` secondary channel that sends the messages `to` the pub/sub on the `message-bus`. All you do is to connect to this pub/sub with as many tap streams (as subscribers for this) to `receive` data.

Hence I believe creating tap would make sense in your case.

Comment: Tap is to provide data for Monitoring/logging; is it a best practice to persist data to data store like updating a record in DBMS?

Comment: Tap is used to provide data for parallel analysis on various endpoints from the main stream. You can use it along with any number of processors and a sink. and this sink can be a analytic repo or a data store.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time and appreciate it.

I found a cleaner way to implement to update multiple backends with Dynamic Route as a sink. Dynamic Router then streams data based on a  header value to Stream A and Stream B which will have sinks to update backend RDBMS.

Tap, I am not convinced to update the business critical data to backends and it is a WireTap impl.

Thanks
Karthik